# Custom TableViewCell with SwipeCellKit

Tags: swift, uitableview, swipe

I have a problem with the understanding of the pod SwipeCellKit.

I have this simple setup (Firebase for retrieving the data)

On my :

```
class MyFriendsViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var MyFriendsTableview: UITableView!
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var MyFriendslist = [MyFriendsModel]()
```

And I have my cellForRowAt like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomFriends", for: indexPath) as! MyFriendsTableViewCell

     //   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomFriends") as! SwipeTableViewCell
      //  cell.delegate = self
```

When I try to implement the swipeCellKit, I loose my references from my MyFriendTableViewCell (UIimage,label references) if I put :

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomFriends") as! SwipeTableViewCell
   cell.delegate = self
```

Anyone knows how to unblock this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just change **this:**

```
class MyFriendsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { ...
```

To **this:**

```
class MyFriendsTableViewCell: SwipeTableViewCell { ...
```

We've just inherited from `SwipeTableViewCell` class. After this change, you will be able to use your `MyFriendsTableViewCell` properties and `SwipeTableViewCell` properties.

**Updated code:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomFriends", for: indexPath) as! MyFriendsTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
    ...
    cell.yourMyFriendsTableCellProperty = ...
    return cell
}
```